# How to connect Ubuntu 20.04 server to internet through a windows 10 laptop with wifi connectivity

Tags: networking, server, network-bridge

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 server on DL360 G8. My installation place does not have internet. I can only access internet through my mobile data where also my laptop is hot spotting.

I established a network connectivity -using Ethernet cables- between the laptop and the Ubuntu server and created a local network 192.168.3.0. I can access the server from the laptop using putty.

How can I proceed from here to enable the Ubuntu server reach the internet through the laptop. in other words what network configuration is required at the server side and what configuration is required at the laptop side.

I need this connectivity badly to complete the required server updates. Please help

Comment: It sounds like you only have access to a WiFi network, so your server needs a WiFi adapter to connect to it. What am I missing?

Comment: thank you for your reply. but that does not answer my question. wifi adapter needs configuration and setup  files which i am not able to reach now.